# Registering OCX file manually

Tags: c++, dll, activex

I have deeveloped an activex component using vs2008. I used MFC to develop it.

I tried to register the component manually using the command

regsvr32 mycontrol.ocx but it throwed an error "Load library" failed. I am sure it is because of dependent dll. I used dependency walker and found out the dlls. now what should i do to make it work.

Comment: So you know what DLLs you're missing, but don't know what to do about it? (Not sure I understand your question.)

Comment: @Mat: I think i should try what Mazhar has mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled the project using MFC as Statically linked and it resolved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are running the 64 bit version of regsvr32 and your OCX is 32 bit. Since regsvr32 loads the OCX DLL into its process, you must use the 32 bit version of regsvr32. That can be found in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: what should i do with the dependent MFC dll's? should i compile my solution with MFC staticaly linked?

Comment: Linking MFC statically is certainly one option. If you link dynamically to MFC then you need to deploy the DLLs to somewhere in the DLL search path. But my suspicion is that your immediate problem is due to running on a 64 bit machine. Of course, I am guessing a little because you have not yet confirmed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the dll files under system32 folder, see if it works, mine worked just fine

Comment: This is poor advice. You should never modify the system directory. It belongs to the system and you respect it and leave it alone.

Comment: tell us if you've another solution